# Android: The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (ListViewAdapter, String, int)

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using the toast inside filter class. Here is the code for it

```
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        expressionlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            expressionlist.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (Expression wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getWord().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    expressionlist.add(wp);
                }
            }
            if(expressionlist.size() == 0){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No match found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                   // add all items of expressionlist
                expressionlist.addAll(arraylist);
                }

        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I am getting error The method `makeText(Context, CharSequence, int)` in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments `(ListViewAdapter, String, int)`
How can I solve this?

Comment: Pass context to adapter class and use this context instead of this keyword.

Comment: Simply because a ListViewAdaper is not a subclass of Context. You need to get the context of your application, which is the current Activity (to keep it simple)

Comment: You could've solved this by using your brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer context ie `getApplicationContext()` or pass the ListViewAdapter's context.

Context can be an `Activity` or `Fragment`

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "No match found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```